# Data Sync between local database and online database

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, azure

I am developing a C# based window store app which has GUI developed using WPF.

The application's database is already on the Cloud through Windows Azure, but, I also want to have local copy of it through SQLite

Now, my question is:

How can I synchronize the data between Windows Azure and SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Azure Offline Sync. [This tutorial may help you](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/) which states:

> Offline support will allow you to interact with a local database when
>   your app is in an offline scenario. Once your app is online with the
>   backend database, you sync your local changes using the offline
>   features.

[this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-155-Offline-Storage-with-Donna-Malayeri) may also help support the tutorial

Comment: even if the local database is in SQL lite?

Comment: Yes this is for SQLite